# Hiding content on dom-load

Tags: javascript, dom

I am making a chrome extension that is supposed to beautify a certain site. I am hiding all elements on domload except one. But the problem with it is that everytime the site loads ,first everything gets loaded, and then it gets hidden. here is my code

```
window.onload = function(){

var all = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
var viewer = document.getElementById("viewer").style;

for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++) {
    all[i].style.visibility='hidden';
}

viewer.visibility='visible';

};
```

I hope there is a better way of doing this than what I am doing right now, which is basically loading all the content hiding all the content and then making a certain component visible.
This whole process is quite slow and the user can see the content I am trying to hide on pageload.

Is there any way to specify via javascript which content is to be loaded , or to make the whole process fast enough for it to be not noticed ?

Comment: `window.onload` is the wrong event. ["While JavaScript provides the load event for executing code when a page is rendered, this event does not get triggered until all assets such as images have been completely received."](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) You need to execute your code sooner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery here would be your friend.  It is very fast.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div').not('#viewer').hide();
});
```